# Autocomplete of a file name in bash prompt

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I usually put a date before a file or directory name similar to `2014-04-20 file_name.doc`.

So, in a folder there is usually a bunch of files and directories starting with a date.

But when accessing these folders from command line, bash in my case, it is a little annoying, because I have to type all the dates and only after that hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> for autocomplete.

What I want is to type only some part of the file name and after hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> the system should put the full name on prompt.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `zsh` supports this behaviour.

Comment: `fish` also support it.

Comment: I tried `fish` -- excellent!

Answer (score 3):

Complete a wildcard pattern:

```
ls *file_n*Tab
```

If the pattern matches multiple files, you'll be prompted for choices or the list will be interpolated into the command line, depending on your completion options. If you want to cancel that and type a few more characters to restrict the matches, undo the completion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>).

If you use context-sensitive completion, <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't expand wildcards by default (there may be an option you can set to rectify that), but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `complete` to do what you want (existing completion script are located in /etc/bash_completion.d under debian, after installing the appropriate package)

You can  check the apache2.2-common to have a basic example.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use `\eg` (`glob-complete-word`), you don't need to type the second asterisk, or you can for example type `*file_n\eg` instead of `*file_n*<tab>`.

If there are multiple files that match the pattern, you can insert the first match with `menu-complete` or the last match with `menu-complete-backward`. If you for example add

```
"\et": menu-complete
"\er": menu-complete-backward
```

to `~/.inputrc`, `*file_n*\et` completes to the first match and `*file_n*\er` completes to the last match.